# In Entity Framework 5 CodeFirst, how to create a query that will return when any pair of values are found?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have an unknown number of complex keys passed into my function at runtime. They will be structured like this:

```
var keys = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "1", "a" },
    new List<string> { "2", "b" },
    new List<string> { "3", "c" }
};
```

The inner list will always have two values. The outter list could have n values. I am attempting to query a table where records match any of the pairs in the List. I tried this query like this:

```
var filtered =
    dataContext.T.Where(
        s => keys.Any(k => 
                k[0] == s.Column0 
                && k[1] == s.Column1));
```

At this point, LinqToEntities fails because it seems that linq is unable to process lists (or arrays?) inside an .Any() method.

This is the error I get when I run this code:

```
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
```

So my question is, how can I query for records that match any pair of values in the lists? I can change anything about the structure as long as I can query for any in a set of pairs.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Instead of a list of two-item lists, have you considered using a list of tuples?  Don't know Entities enough to say for sure, but it might help.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll try that quick.

Comment: Unfortunately, the tuple idea didn't work: {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Tuple`2'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you can use any enumerable like that in linq 2 entities.

One workaround would be to concatenate your pairs, with a "should never appear" string in the middle.

```
var concatenatedkeys = keys.Select(m => m[0] + "~" + m[1]).ToList();

var filtered = 
     dataContext.T.Where(s => concatenatedKeys.Contains(
                                             s.Column0 ?? string.Empty + 
                                             "~" + 
                                             s.Column1));
```

Comment: Would this require EF to enumerate results in order to compare?

Comment: @quakkels no, it won't, l2E is able to do string concatenation.

Comment: It didn't work at first, but then I realized that the columns were char instead of varchar. I just needed to add a `.Trim()` and it worked like a charm. Thanks! You saved my bacon!

Comment: Never heard this one, thanx for the smile ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer does solve the problem that I posed in the question. However, I ran into a similar issue once I needed to compare values across linked entities.

The concatenation solution ran into problems with this scenario:

```
var filtered = 
     dataContext.T.Where(s => concatenatedKeys.Contains(
                                             s.AnotherEntity.Column0 ?? string.Empty + 
                                             "~" + 
                                             s.AnotherEntity.Column1));
```

To solve this, I ended up using [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to create the .Where() expression using the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).